# Crash reports from app on App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store, crash-reports

I have just released an application on the App Store but for some users the app will crash. I am not able to reproduce this problem and therefore I was wondering if there is any way to get a crash report from the user so that I can get an idea of why the app will crash.

Comment: please reconsider the approved answer

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Being only a very part-time iOS developer and having a small app that doesn't have too much going on, I've not until recently had cause to try and find crash logs. Google led me to this very old thread.

Just in case anyone else ends up on the same wild goose chase - at the time of writing (mid-2018) iTunes Connect has been rebuilt as App Store Connect and, in the web portal, all you can see is *number* of crashes and so-forth. To download energy usage and crash report logs from Apple servers, you actually go to XCode. `Window` -> `Organizer` -> `Energy` or `Crashes` tab **[EDIT: Still correct in June 2022, XCode 13.4.1]**.

Comment: What about apps crashing in Testflight?

Comment: Also, a tip to get to the raw crash logs since it also was not obvious: once in the Organizer **Crashes** tab, right-click on the crash in the list under your app and choose **Show in Finder...** In the Finder, right-click on the .xccrashpoint file and choose **Show Package Contents**... then navigate down to `DistributionInfos/all/Logs` to find the actual crash logs.

Comment: @SilentLucidity go to your app in iTunesConnect (AppStore Connect), in the header tab select `TestFlight`, in the left panel under `Feedback` there is `Crashes`. Click on that and select a crash from the list you want, then in the popup, click on the cloud download icon to get the crash.zip. Unzip it, open the .crash file in your Xcode app project.

Comment: @CyberMew Unzipping the file only shows a JSON with the same information you get when clicking in TestFlight. I can't find a .crash file, anything changed?

Comment: @FredFlinstone It has been a while and I no longer have access, so I wouldn’t be able to advise further unfortunately

Comment: This is no longer the case, at least not today with Xcode Version 13.4.1 (13F100). The crashes item is in Organizer but no crashes appear there (despite them showing up on App Store Connect's website).

Comment: @internetdotcom just re-tested on 13.4.1 and after an age watching a "Downloaded crashes list..." spinner, it did show the expected information. It's probably just very buggy ;-) but just in case, check that the various filter menus along the top of the window are set correctly.

Comment: @AndrewHodgkinson Interesting. The report details still haven't shown up for any devs on my team. All of my filters are set to "All". (And it did work a few weeks ago). Ah well. Hopefully they're getting reports from the organizer failures.

Comment: Well, as developers, we're all well aware of Apple's software quality these days. Sorry to hear you've hit yet another one of their bugs and hope you can find a workaround, as based on recent performance, Apple themselves are unlikely to fix it.

Comment: If anyone else is on a Macbook and can't find the Window option in the toolbar, it was pushed to the right of notch for me and I didn't see it for a while

Comment: I see zero crashes. I haven't heard of any crashes, but the app has been used quite extensively for quite a while. Is it possible that this only shows crashes of "internal testing" users?

Answer (score 5):

URL : https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=nra79npr

But make sure you have configured your appstoreconnects credentials in xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can get crash reports via iTunes Connect.  Here's how:

1. Log into [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com)
2. Click "Manage your Applications"
3. Select your app
4. Click the app icon under "Current Version"
5. Click "Crash Reports" on the right side

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. Though, when I go there, there are no crash reports even though I know that the app crashes for some people. Do you know if there is any way to retrieve a crash report directly from the phone?

Comment: There is a way to, but the user would have to be a registered developer and have access to xcode.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll just have to wait and see if the reports will show up in iTunes Connect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See Andrew Hodgkinson comment below. This is no longer the correct answer.

Comment: One important point, for a full crash report with stack trace, the user needs to enable sharing crash report (even internal AppStore Connect testers).  On the device: `Privacy -> Analytics & Improvements -> Share iPhone Analytics (and Share with App Developers)`.   If it's not enabled you still get a basic crash report (only directly downloadable from AppStore Connect, not Xcode organizer). It only has some device info, but no stack trace or `.crash` file.   This is why some crash show up in Organizer and others don't.

Comment: This is no longer valid in 2024. Crashes are only available under Test Flight which are reported by testers, not from real users. Please update this answer or remove it as it is showing higher than correct answers that reflect current AppStore Connect.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone is still looking for this answer in 2019, here is how i did it.
1.) Login to Apple iTunes Connect
2.) Goto My Apps >> Select your app >> Activity
3.) Select your build number
4.) Select Download dSYM in General information

The below link helped me and you can find other ways to download dSYM (e.g.: from Xcode) from here.
References: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-ios/configuration/retrieve-dsyms-bitcode-apps

Comment: This is only applicable to bitcode-enabled apps (you get dsym for your app from Apple). This does not 'show' you app crashes nor the stack trace. Of course in any case you need the dsyms to see the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

**Update on 22-December-2023:**

Now we can see the Crash Feedback from the app store from Test Flight.

1. Login to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/
2. Go to `Test Flight`
3. Under `Feedback` select `Crashes`
4. On Mouse over you can see the `Open in Xcode` button
5. Click on that `Open in Xcode` to see the crash log

Note: Only includes feedback from testers running iOS 13, visionOS 1.0 or macOS 12 or later.

Answer (score -1):

hey i thorogly search and find this

iOS 5 and later Tapping Settings > General > About > Diagnostics & Usage will allow you to choose between Automatically Send and Don't Send.

iOS 4 and earlier By default, opting in is a one-time decision. If you'd like to change your decision, you can reset warnings for your iOS 4 or earlier device so that you will be asked again.

How to reset warnings within iTunes Connect your iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch to your PC or Mac. Wait until your device has appeared on the left side of the iTunes window under Devices. Right-click (Mac or PC) or Control-click (Mac) the icon for your device. From the shortcut menu, choose Reset Warnings:

The next time you sync after resetting warnings, you should see:

To disagree and stop sending Apple diagnostic and usage information, click No Thanks.

If you don't see the window above Disconnect your device from your computer. Open an application on your device. Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button until the red slider appears, and then press and hold the Home button until the application quits. If you're using iOS 2.x or earlier, press and hold the Home button until the application quits. Connect your device and sync it with iTunes. The option to agree or disagree to diagnostics collection should appear again.

Chearz;)