# Notifications for crash reports listed on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

Is there a way that Apple, Xcode or something notifies you when your app has crashed?
I am not talking about 3rd party stuff like Crashlytics and such, I am talking about the crash reports from the Organizer.

I would like to stop depending on 3rd party SDKs and the reports from Xcode seems pretty good too, the big downside is that as far as I know there is no way to be notified when they happened.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's another big downside. You don't always get the stacktrace - dependant on the users privacy preferences. Read also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145665/crash-reports-from-app-on-app-store#comment106192421_10145713

Comment: yeah you right, for some reason I though that that setting applies also for the third party ones, I thought it was some kind of a global setting, thanks for pointing that out!